# Return a dictionary from a pandas dataframe query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataset from with a set of football games I am analysing. I would like to return a dictionary of all games where the home team scored more than 2 goals, with the structure {team, home_goals...} in increasing order.

I have so far tried two different approaches without success. The first one returns ("Nr of goals", TRUE), the second one returns an error in the form of "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()".

Tips?

1.

more_than_2 = (df["home_goals"] > 2)

more_than_2_sorted = sorted(more_than_2.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

print(more_than_2_sorted)

2.

more_than_2 = (df["home_goals"] > 2)

more_than_2_sorted = {more_than_2["team"], more_than_2["home_goals"], reverse = True}

print(more_than_2_sorted)

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a dummy dataset for this problem

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'team': ['A']*3 + ['B']*3 + ['C']*4 ,
     'home_goals': np.random.randint(0,6,10)
    }
)
```

[image]

Next steps are as follows

- Filter for more than two goals
- Sort the data frame
- Convert the data frame to dictionary

```
# Using pandas method chaining
more_than_2 = (df
  .query('home_goals>2')
  .sort_values(by='home_goals')
  .to_dict('list')
)
```

The output looks like below.

```
{'home_goals': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
 'team': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']}
```

The desired output can be obtained by zipping the two lists that we get as output.

```
dict(zip(more_than_2['team'], more_than_2['home_goals']))
```

**Note**: There should be no duplicate records in the team columns since a python dictionary doesn't support duplicate indices.